# "add to" vs "add in" which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I have a question about a preposition collocation.
Between "Please add it to the cost" and "Please add it in the cost" which one is idiomatic?

Comment: You add ***to*** the cost, not *in*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Kris

Comment: You could, however, add it ***into*** the cost.

Comment: "add it into the cost", got it! thank you!